# Display select2 ajax results into template

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have select2 displaying data after making an ajax call.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#citySelect").select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap-5',
            placeholder: "Search for your city",
            dropdownAutoWidth: true,
            width: 'auto',
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            allowClear: true,
            async: true,
            ajax: {
                url:
                    function (params) {
                        return '@GatewaySettings.Value.Url' + '/api/location/cities/' + params.term;
                    },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: 'GET',
                processResults: function (result) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(result, function (item) {
                            return { id: item.id, text: item.city };
                        }),
                    };
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am able to search for a list of cities

I would like for the active search results to display as city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zip (i.e. Los Angeles, California 90001) and after a selection display just the city (i.e Los Angeles).

I am trying to follow the documentation, but I keep getting an undefined result.

[image]

Here is the output from the console
[image]

I am sure I am just not understanding how to use the [templating](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating).

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#citySelect").select2({
            theme: 'bootstrap-5',
            placeholder: "Search for your city",
            dropdownAutoWidth: true,
            width: 'auto',
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            allowClear: true,
            async: true,
            templateResult: function (item) {
                console.log(item);
                return item.city + ', ' + item.state + ' ' + item.zip;
            },
            templateSelection: function (item) {
                return item.city
            },
            ajax: {
                url:
                    function (params) {
                        return '@GatewaySettings.Value.Url' + '/api/location/cities/' + params.term;
                    },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: 'GET',
                cache: true,
                processResults: function (result) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(result, function (item) {
                            return { id: item.id, text: item.city };
                        }),
                    };
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help appreciated

Results from console after adding

```
console.log("RESULTS", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));

RESULTS [
  {
    "id": 5039,
    "city": "Chandlers Valley",
    "state": "Pennsylvania",
    "zip": null
  },
  {
    "id": 14327,
    "city": "Chandlersville",
    "state": "Ohio",
    "zip": null
  },
  {
    "id": 15915,
    "city": "Chandler",
    "state": "Indiana",
    "zip": null
  },
  {
    "id": 19293,
    "city": "Chandler",
    "state": "Minnesota",
    "zip": null
  },
  {
    "id": 22001,
    "city": "Chandlerville",
    "state": "Illinois",
    "zip": null
  },
  {
    "id": 26294,
    "city": "Chandler",
    "state": "Oklahoma",
    "zip": null
  },
  {
    "id": 26686,
    "city": "Chandler",
    "state": "Texas",
    "zip": null
  },
  {
    "id": 29715,
    "city": "Chandler",
    "state": "Arizona",
    "zip": null
  },
  {
    "id": 29716,
    "city": "Chandler",
    "state": "Arizona",
    "zip": null
  },
  {
    "id": 29717,
    "city": "Chandler",
    "state": "Arizona",
    "zip": null
  }
]
```

Comment: What exactly is _"an undefined error"_? Please [edit] your question to include the **actual** error message, in full

Comment: I updated the question with the error from chrom dev tools

Comment: Cheers. So why did you change your `processResults`? The original uses the `data` directly as an array but your new version uses `data.items`, so which is correct?

Comment: I thought by setting the id and text values in "processResults" i was making the additional elements unavailable to the templating functions, which is why I was attempting to return the items all their properties. I see my assumption is not correct. I have updated the processResults function and updated the questions with the new undefined error from a screen shot

Comment: sorry its late and Im a little tired. I have removed from errors from the question. i have updated the questions with output from the console

Comment: Which is why I thought my process results function was coded incorrectly.

Comment: Why are your `zip` properties all `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$.map()` is largely redundant and also excludes the properties you appear to want to use.

All you really need to do is nest the array under a `results` property so Select2 can make use of it.

```js
templateResult: ({ city, state, zip }) =>
  `${city}, ${state} ${zip ?? ""}`.trim(),
templateSelection: ({ city }) => city,
ajax: {
  url: ({ term }) =>
    "@GatewaySettings.Value.Url" +
    `/api/location/cities/${encodeURIComponent(term)}`, // encode the term
  processResults: (results) => ({ results }),
}
```

Some notes about the `ajax` properties...

- The default method (type) is `GET`
- The default `cache` property is `true`
- GET requests don't have content so don't require a `contentType`

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much. I altered one of my queries from dapper to alias ZipCode to Zip and now it works!. I will review what you did tomorrow so that I can learn going forward